# Create Azure Linux VM with SSHPublicKeys Fail

Tags: azure

```
    $servicename="vmlinux" 
    Remove-AzureService -ServiceName $servicename -Force
    New-AzureService -ServiceName $servicename -AffinityGroup affinitgroup
    Add-AzureCertificate -ServiceName $servicename -CertToDeploy .\myCert.cer
    New-AzureVM -ServiceName $servicename -VMs (( New-AzureVMConfig -Name $servicename -InstanceSize Small -ImageName imagename | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -LinuxUser test -Password "password" -SSHPublicKeys (New-AzureSSHKey -PublicKey -Fingerprint 690076D4C41C1DE677CD464EA63B44AE94C2E621 -Path /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys) |  Set-AzureEndpoint -Name "SSH" -LocalPort "22" -PublicPort "22" -Protocol "tcp"  ))
```

No error message shows. But /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys is not created

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The "authorized_keys" file was being created, but it was blank. I found out the private key was in the wrong format. I had to run the following command on my existing key to generate a new key compatible with Azure:

```
openssl req -x509 -key existingKey.key -nodes  -days 3000 -newkey rsa:2048 -out newkey.cer
```

After the newkey.cer is generated, obtain the fingerprint of the certificate and retry your commands with this certificate instead of the old one.